# Why can't access specific object in array element?

Tags: angular, typescript

```
   async ngOnInit() {
    debugger;
    let value: any 
    let allPricingData: [] = await this.extApi.getPriceData();

    allPricingData.forEach((element) => {
      value = element.Subject;
    })
  }
```

allPricingData = there is contain array like following

```
0: {Subject: "Maths", Grade: "11", Type: "Theory", MaxPrice: 1000}
1: {Subject: "Maths", Grade: "12", Type: "Theory", MaxPrice: 2000}
2: {Subject: "Maths", Grade: "13", Type: "Theory", MaxPrice: 3000}
3: {Subject: "Science", Grade: "10", Type: "Theory", MaxPrice: 4000}
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I try to get all Subject values to **value** variable Then i want to push it another array! So i can't access only subject using **element.Subject** it showing "**Property 'Subject' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339)**"

how to fix?

[image]

Comment: You should note that this is TypeScript and not vanilla JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `allPricingData: []` to `allPricingData: any[]` or create a type to strongly type it rather than using any.

```
interface myResponseType {
  Subject: string;
  Grade: string;
  Type: string;
  MaxPrice: number;
}
```

and use it

`allPricingData: myResponseType[]`

Comment: Oh! It's work, thank you so much! Can you tell me reason of that?

Comment: Because `[]` is an array of undefined and `any[]` is an array of any type.